# Hadamard block matrix proof

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

$A$ is a Hadamard matrix of side $n$, and $H$ is a Hadamard matrix of side $m+n$, where $H=\pmatrix{A& B \\\ C& D}$ for some matrices $B,C,D$. Prove that $m \geq  n$.

A Hadamard matrix is a square matrix of side n with entries -1,1 and $HH^t=nI$. I'm assuming I have to use the following facts that I know about Hadamard matrices:
The rows and columns are pairwise orthogonal.

Every HM can be normalized ($1$'s in the first row and column)

$n+m$ is 1, 2 or a multiple of $4$

I'm not sure how to prove this...help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing out the product $HH^t$ in block form.  One of the blocks will be $AA^t+BB^t$.  What must this block be equal to if $H$ is Hadamard?  What can you say about the rank of $B$ if $m<n$?  Can you produce a contradiction in this way?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the block is $AA^t + BB^t$. In transpose of matrix H you need to switch B and C blocks and transpose them.

Comment: @BřetislavHájek Yes, you are correct.  Thanks for catching that.  I will fix the post.